# Search results missing for some users in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, sharepoint-list

I have a list in SharePoint Online with roughly 8k items and have a user who is trying to search for a list item using the title field.  When he searches for the item the query yields no results, but when I search using the same term it returns the desired item.

Does anyone have any idea of why this could be happening and a potential fix?

Comment: Does the list have Item-Level permission enabled? Do you and the user have the same permission for this list? Are you searching like [Title]:"SomeText" or just typing in text in the search box?

Comment: The list has item level permissions and we manage that using groups.  I just found out that they were able to see it after I gave them full control perms to the item but the group theyre in that's also attached to the item should also work.. but doesn't... so that's the next thing to figure out

Comment: This seems to be then a permission issue. You can verify the group's permission at the item level and then troubleshoot accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what group you are using, but I’ve just run a test on an Office 365 group and confirmed:

If you have enabled **[Item-level Permissions](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/)** (via *List settings > Advanced settings*) and without setting extra unique permission, **Read** permission is enough for a user/group to get search results from this list.

Users within an Office 365 group will get inheritance without issue. It might take a few minutes, but you can test in another list just to confirm.

If you have trouble passing the user permissions, you can remove the group along with the users from this site via the User Information List (`_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`), then reconfigure the permission again to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me recently. Depending on the total items in the list or document library, you will have to WAIT for some hours. In my case, i have 62942 document in my document library, my user had to wait for like 12 hours for the page to properly index for the user. This usually happen when you just add the user to the list or document library. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reindex SPO Site / SPO Library - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content. It might help